# basic linux executable path does not show up

Tags: shell, command, which

I am trying to find the path of basic commands like `ls` or `cd` using `which` command. I see the path for `ls` but not for `cd`. Of course both the commands work fine. Any idea?

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$ which cd
$
```

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is always built-in command provided by the shell itself. It will not be found as an external utility. This is in no way specific to Linux.

From the ["APPLICATION USAGE" section for `cd` in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_16):

> Since `cd` affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in. If it is called in a subshell or separate utility execution environment, such as one of the following:

```
(cd /tmp)
nohup cd
find . -exec cd {} \;
```

> it does not affect the working directory of the caller's environment.

---

A portable way of finding the path of a command is to use `command -v`:

```
bash-4.4$ command -v ls
/bin/ls
bash-4.4$ command -v cd
cd
```

`type` will be slightly more verbose:

```
bash-4.4$ type ls
ls is /bin/ls
bash-4.4$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

See also "[Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)"